# User Input on Python Script

Tags: python

I'm new to python, but I have a script that works as needed. However, some of these fields need to be updated with new data each usage: Filepath, Description, and External-Identifier.

What is the best way to enter this data, short of rewriting the python script each time I need it? I was thinking something like a GUI user-input form, but I'm not sure how to do this.

I'm using the Library of Congress's BagIt tool (Python).  Here is the script:

```
import bagit

# load the bag
bag = bagit.Bag('<FILEPATH>')
# update bag info metadata
bag.info['Source-Organization'] = ['University Archives']
bag.info['Organization-Address'] = ["#"]
bag.info['Contact-Phone'] = ['#']
bag.info['Contact-Email'] = ['#']
bag.info['Description'] = ['#DESCRIPTION#']
bag.info['External-Identifier'] = ['#UUID#']
bag.save(manifests=True)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

---

UPDATE. Thanks to the help, here is a working version of the UDbaginfo.py script. This updates bag-info.txt and updates the bag manifest.

Here is the code to update the bag-info.txt file for LOC Bagit (Python version)

```
import bagit

fpath = input("Enter the file path:")
bagDes = input("Enter the Description:")
bagUUID = input("Enter the UUID:")

# load the bag
bag = bagit.Bag(fpath)

# update bag info metadata
bag.info['Source-Organization'] = ['University Archives']
bag.info['Organization-Address'] = ["1000 North Ave. Nowhere, State. 
33333"]
bag.info['Contact-Phone'] = ['555-555-5555']
bag.info['Contact-Email'] = ['archives@university.edu']
bag.info['Description'] = [bagDes]
bag.info['External-Identifier'] = [bagUUID]
bag.save(manifests=True)
```

Comment: How do you envision this working? do you want to prompt in the console for user input, or have the inputs passed in as arguments when the script is initiated?

Comment: Which ever would be easier. A prompt for user input would be fine though.

Comment: You can prompt for user input with, for example, `fpath=input("Enter the file path:")` which will save the input as a string to the variable

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Python 3 you could use `input()`. This would allow you to validate as well, i.e.:

```
#Validate
validUUID = False
while  not (validUUID):
    temp_uuid = input("UUID:")
    try:
        int(temp_uuid)
        bag.info['External-Identifier'] = temp_uuid
        validUUID = True
```

Although the above method is only in a terminal context. Alternatively you could just pass arguments to the script